# Editable UIWebView in iPhone

Tags: iphone

I have seen some write about making a UIWebView editable. I would like to be able to compose a message containing both text and images the WYSIWYG way, and I thought that I might do it with a UIWebView.

Is this a good solution and how do I do this? I have searched the web for examples, but found none.

Thank you

Comment: Hi Neigaard ,I have also the same question, have you found the solution

Answer (score 7):

`UIWebView` content can be made editable starting with iOS 5.0+.

A very nice tutorial can be viewed here: http://ios-blog.co.uk/tutorials/rich-text-editing-a-simple-start-part-1/

The tutorial goes beyond the question, so here's a resume of how to make the `UIWebView` editable:

```
//index.html

<html>
 <body>
   <div id="content" contenteditable="true" style="font-family: Helvetica">This is out Rich Text Editing View </div>
  </body>
</html>


//somewhere.m

NSBundle *bundle = [NSBundle mainBundle];
NSURL *indexFileURL = [bundle URLForResource:@"index" withExtension:@"html"];
[webView loadRequest:[NSURLRequest requestWithURL:indexFileURL]];
```

Anyway, I suggest reading the tutorial, since it shows how to do other stuff as well (changing fonts, colors, embedding images etc.)

Answer (score 0):

You could use the **loadHTML:baseURL** method from the UIWebView class reference:

http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UIWebView_Class/Reference/Reference.html

Place this in the **textViewDidEndEditing:** delegate method of the UITextView:

http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UITextView_Class/Reference/UITextView.html

Comment: I do not understand this answer? I know I can load some static html in a UIWebView, but what did you mean by placing what into the textViewDidEndEditing of a UITextView? Should I both have a UITextView and a UIWebView, and then what?

Comment: You could place both a UITextView and UIWebView in the same window. By editing the text in the text view, you would load that string into the web view. The web view would then render that string into a HTML page.

Comment: @EvanMulawski How can we display html in textView like apple's mail app does when we forward a html mail?

Answer (score 0):

Actually UIWebView way is so painful, mobile safari does not support WYSIWYG rich text editor area.

From [Zoho FAQ](http://writer.zoho.com/public/help/zohowriterfaq/fullpage#iPhone) :

**I can't create or edit documents on my iPhone, the keyboard doesn't show up when opening iZoho on iPhone. What's the problem?**

*It is an issue with the iPhone as the safari browser doesn't seem to recognize the rich text editor area and hence the keyboard isn't appearing. This is not an iZoho specific problem as all the applications that use a WYSIWYG editor face the same issue. We hope that Apple will address this issue soon and come up with the next version of iPhone's Safari that supports rich text editing. As a workaround, we may give a plain text editor for users to edit/create their documents if this isn't corrected in Safari's next version.*

You should implement rich text editing by yourself :(